# Change shortcut key for "Highlight URL" function in Chrome

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut

I recently got a Mac in addition to my Linux laptop. I've tried to change around settings so that I don't have to use new shortcuts.

The issue I am facing is that I use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to highlight the URL **all the time** in Chrome. In Mac, the default shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

I've changed up some Chrome shortcuts using the App Shortcuts option in  Keyboard Preferences. This triggers menu items when you use your custom keyboard shortcuts. However, there is no menu item for highlight URL, and hence I am not able to use this option.

I've also tried the extension [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck), but it has no function to highlight URL.

I'd like to use the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut on my Mac as well. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The menu was actually called **Open Location**.

I then used App Shortcuts in Keyboard Preferences to set it to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.